# Intercept ActiveMQ message with Camel

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, interceptor

I need to register the time a message leaves ActiveMQs queue.
I have Q1 and the consumer is a java application on Jboss server through activemq-ra.rar.

Is it possible to do that with Camel (included in ActiveMQ) interceptor?
I am not programmer, so solution in XML DSL will be perfect.

Any help would be appreciated. thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using advisoryForConsumed and forwarding the advisory messages to a queue solved the problem for me.

In activemq.xml:

```
<destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry queue="Q1" advisoryForConsumed="true"/>
        </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

then forwarding ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue.Q1 to another queue, AvisoryConsumed.

```
<destinationInterceptors> 
    <virtualDestinationInterceptor> 
        <virtualDestinations> 
            <compositeTopic name="ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue.Q1" >
                <forwardTo><queue physicalName="AvisoryConsumed" /> </forwardTo>
        </compositeTopic>
    </virtualDestinations>
</virtualDestinationInterceptor>
```

then when a message is consumed, there will be a message with brokerOutTime in AvisoryConsumed and the original message's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the logging broker plugin. It can output the information to a log, which you can then use to build your metric.

ref: [Logging Broker Plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/logging-interceptor)

Comment: thanks, but those data have no timestamp

Comment: Log output generally includes a timestamp when the log output is executed by default. You can also customize the timestamp format to make it easier to parse if you need to build reports or put the log file in a database

Comment: Is that log4 j.properties you're thinking about? If I set logConsumerEvents in plugins, then no outputs in activemq.log have timestamp at all. How to force it to show the timestamp? I do appreciate any hints.